# How do I build on specific commit in Git on Jenkins?

Tags: git, svn, jenkins

I am trying to build my project from a specific commit, in Jenkins.

I have specified the branch to build and it's building from the HEAD commit.

However I want to build from any specific revision/commit.

I tried passing a `GIT_COMMIT` value as a parameter but it's picking up the HEAD commit only.

I also tried using svn type thing like `https://svn-url@$REVISION` where REVISION is parameter passed in build.

For git it doesn't recognize `ssh://git-url@REVISION`.

Comment: Pass the commit sha1 to a predefined parameter and in `Build-Execute shell` run `git checkout <commit>` before the build process starts. Some extra work is needed to make sure the check-out goes well.

Comment: i can name commit sha1 parameter any thing ? and then use that value in git checkout <parameter name >

Comment: Check the box `This project is parameterized` and then you can add predefined parameters. For example add a `String Parameter` with `Name` as `build_revision`. `[ -z ${build_revision} ] || git checkout "${build_revision}"`. These predefined parameters will be exported as environment variables.

Comment: okay let me try

Comment: Previous HEAD position was e029d5f... Readme updated for Git
HEAD is now at e5cc423... Updated Readme for GIt push

is this right. my head commit was e029d5f and last revision was e5cc423 i pass parameter value as e5cc423  ?

Answer (score 26):

1. Jenkins Git plugin should be
2. Copy your commit hash and paste it into "Branch Specifier"

[image]
Then Run "Build now"

Comment: @RMati, could you please describe more in details what type of error do you receive or what behaviour of Jenkins you are getting when performing all these steps. 
I often do this and it always works for me.

Comment: Actually I had to put the whole git commit (the full hash number) and that worked afterwards. 
e.g. 9f88e6f6ec09569f6bd40ae76f25d292b512fb85
not the shot commit id. 

Thanks,

Comment: Remove the "Lightweight checkout" checkbox selection. Otherwise commit checkout did not work for me!

Comment: @Codev Thanks for your comment!! I was struggling with this and it worked like a charm after i removed Lightweight checkout

Answer (score 1):

Well I think instead of hacking the build config to point to a specific commit hash, it would be better to just create a new branch, that points to the commit you want to build. If you have a correctly configured Multibranch Pipeline Build, Jenkins should discover and build your commit/branch automatically.

Alternatively you could also use a tag instead of a branch. But in this case you need to add the "Discover tags" Behaviour to your Branch Source Config.

[image: Branch Source Behaviours]